# In the old days

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

The answer is a well known phrase.

---

[image: image of the globe centered on the atlantic ocean with the text CORDPGHGOBLOAMAHSOZAOTOAAE displayed above it]

```
                                 3443355
```

---

Hint1

> The numbers at the bottom are related to the string of letters at the top of the image... but how?

Hint2

> Sum of the digits?

Hint3 (A bit more decisive. Hoping someone will crack this.)

> I initially planned to write them as **(3) (4) (4) (3) (3) (5) (5)**, but thought to myself that would be a lot more obvious. Also, in case you thought that the string of letters are initials of countries - they're not.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Edited now

Comment: If I transcribed it correctly, the text at the top of the image is "CORGPOGHGOBLOAMAHSOZAOTOAAE".  And in case it's helpful, that string contains 27 letters, with 7 O's, 5 A's, 3 G's, 2 H's, and one each of BCELMPRSTZ.

Comment: I understood Hint 3 before you posted it, but sadly rot13(V qba'g frr n jnl gb hafpenzoyr nyy guvf rnfvyl, oehgr-sbepvat frrzf gb or gur bayl bcgvba urer. Orfvqrf "tybor" znlor (?) orvat n jbeq va gurer.)

Comment: @Auribouros rot13(Bx. V pna fnl Vg'f abg *"tybor"* ohg vafgrnq..? Jung pna gur fhofgevatf cbffvoyl ercerfrag?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are the

> Seven Wonders of the Ancient World

The text gives the

> Initial letters of the Wonders and the numbers underneath show us how to break up the string correctly. In summary, we have
>  **COR** = Colossus of Rhodes.
>  **GPOG** = Great Pyramid of Giza.
>  **HGOB** = Hanging Gardens of Babylon.
>  **LOA** = Lighthouse of Alexandria.
>  **MAH** = Mausoleum at Halicarnassus.
>  **SOZAO** = Statue of Zeus at Olympia.
>  **TOAAE** = Temple of Artemis at Ephesus.

Comment: that's got to be it!

Comment: Now the amount of Os make sense

Comment: This is it! Great job 